# How to transfer the id of a certain element to the backend after a click event?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql

I am working on a certain page write now on my project that is responsible for listing movies and after you click them it links you to a page where you can see all the information about the specific movie you clicked on, now I am using SQL on my database and one of my Ideas to that is to transfer the id of the element being pressed after I already taken care of assigning the right id's to the hyperlink that is being clicked on based on the movie you clicked on.My question is how do I take the id of what is being clicked, transfering it to the backend so that I will be able to pull the right information from the database according to that same id.
this is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace WebProject
{
    public partial class movie : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string movieLister = "";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fName = "contentDB.mdf";
            string tableName = "moviesTbl";
            string sqlSelect = $"select * from {tableName}";
            DataTable table = Helper.ExecuteDataTable(fName, sqlSelect);
            int length = table.Rows.Count;
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                movieLister += $"<a href='moviePage.aspx' id='{table.Rows[i]["MOVIEID"]}'><div class='movie-container' ><img src='{table.Rows[i]["movieImageFile"]}'/><div><img src='favourites.png' /> {table.Rows[i]["rating"]}</div><p>{table.Rows[i]["movieName"]}</p></div></a>";
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

this piece of code makes essentially a list of movies and assigning the correct id's relative to movie's description and sending it back to the page, the only thing is I need to know what to do in order to take the id of what movie has been clicked so that I will be able to transfer the correct information to the page from the data base.

I have tried approching multiple resources but none of them seemed to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did not post the page, I am assuming that you are simply spitting out the `movieLister` string like so `{%= movieLister %}` This should generate `a` tags in the format you use in your for loop like so:

```html
<a href='moviePage.aspx' id='{table.Rows[i]["MOVIEID"]}'>
  <div class='movie-container' >
    <img src='{table.Rows[i]["movieImageFile"]}'/>
  <div>
  <img src='favourites.png' /> {table.Rows[i]["rating"]}
</div>
<p>{table.Rows[i]["movieName"]}</p>
</div>
</a>
```

There are 2 issues with this HTML for what you want

1. There are two closing `div` tags without an opening. This is likely a typo but will cause the rendering engine of the browser to get very confused (and likely the StackOverflow syntax highlighter as well)
2. While each link has the `id` attribute pointing to the movie id, that information is not part of the url that will be loaded when you click the link as it is not in the `href` attribute

To fix both of these I would update the outputed html to look something like this:

```html
<a href='moviePage.aspx?id={table.Rows[i]["MOVIEID"]}'> <!-- Update this href to use the id as a query parameter -->
  <div class='movie-container' >
    <img src='{table.Rows[i]["movieImageFile"]}'/>
  <div>
  <img src='favourites.png' /> {table.Rows[i]["rating"]}
<div> <!-- update this tag -->
<p>{table.Rows[i]["movieName"]}</p>
</div>
</a>
```

Then you should be able to update your page handler like so (note I am on a MacBook and cannot validate this ASPX code as .NET Core/5+ uses Razor Pages only):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace WebProject
{
    public partial class movie : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string movieLister = "";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string id = Request["id"];
            string fName = "contentDB.mdf";
            string tableName = "moviesTbl";

            string sqlSelect = $"select * from {tableName}";
            if (id.Length() > 0)
            {
                sqlSelect += $" where id = {id}"
            }

            DataTable table = Helper.ExecuteDataTable(fName, sqlSelect);
            int length = table.Rows.Count;
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                movieLister += $"<a href='moviePage.aspx?id={table.Rows[i]["MOVIEID"]}'><div class='movie-container' ><img src='{table.Rows[i]["movieImageFile"]}'/><div><img src='favourites.png' /> {table.Rows[i]["rating"]}<div><p>{table.Rows[i]["movieName"]}</p></div></a>";
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

### Important Security Notes

The above code is for demonstrating how to get the ID only. In production I would strongly suggest you either convert it to an int or parameterize it to avoid very simple SQL injection attacks.

I also strongly recommend you migrate to .NET Core/5+ and Razor pages as they make asking such questions here and on google much easier as they are self contained and easier to post the full source. [Tim Corey on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/@IAmTimCorey) has great videos at all levels if you want to learn about Razor pages

Comment: thanks a lot the only piece that was missing is that change in the href and the Request id part thanks a lot appriciate it